# How do I call clearInterval from multiple places in my application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

I have a countdown timer that I need to reset from more than one place in my React Native application. I have a service function that returns my updated time string and a variable that the `setInterval` function is saved to via callbacks `returnCountDown` and `returnSetInterval`:

```js
export const getCountdown = (callLength, returnCountDown, returnSetInterval) => {
  let callLengthInMs = Date.parse('1970-01-01T00:' + callLength + 'Z')
  const interval = setInterval(() => parseTimeString(), 1000, returnCountDown)
  const parseTimeString = () => {
    callLengthInMs -= 1000;
    const timeLeft = new Date(callLengthInMs).toISOString().slice(14, -5)
    returnCountDown(timeLeft);
  }
  returnSetInterval(interval);
}
```

Then in my function component I save the returned `setInterval` function to state and call it under a certain condition, but `clearInterval` does not work:

```js
const CountDown = () => {

  const [time, setTime] = useState(null);
  const [callInterval, setCallInterval] = useState(null);
  const callLength = useSelector(state => state.videosession.callLength);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountdown(callLength, returnCountDown, returnSetInterval);
  }, []);

  const returnCountDown = timeLeft => {
    setTime(timeLeft);
  }

  const returnSetInterval = interval => {
    setCallInterval(interval)
  }

  time === '00:05' && console.log('00:05 HIT') && clearInterval(callInterval); // does not work.
```

How can I achieve being able to call `clearInterval` via an exported module if this is not the correct approach?

#### Update

When I `console.log(typeof interval)` I get `number`. This is the variable that is assigned to `setInterval`

Comment: Put the interval reference in your state instead of a local variable and it can be controlled by calling an action that calls `clearInterval()` on the state variable.

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish - I am putting the variable `interval` in to state - could you explain what you mean a bit more for me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with React per se, but in Vue you would store the reference in a place it can be reached from more than one place (state). Then you would make a mutation that you dispatch to make the change, and/or an action that commits it to state (under Vuex).

Comment: Ok yes, I'm already storing it to state.

Comment: The second part is to create a specific state modifier (action or mutation) that actually calls the `clearInterval()` on that state variable (and sets it to null or whatnot). Then you can call that state modifier from anywhere.

Comment: What ReactJS does is a bit different than Vue when it comes to state. So I don't quite know how to demonstrate it. This [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) shows a clock with a `setInterval()` integrated, although you may not want to unmount. However, it may be you need to manage your reference(s) centrally in it's own component, so you can reach them independently of the `CountDown` component instances, or register those components with a way to find and call a method on the right one (if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Well if its just about one component then,

```
ComponentDidMount=()=>{
 this.interval = setInterval(()=>{}, 1000);
}

ComponentWillUnmount=()=>{
clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

If its not just one component then you may need to use redux that allow's Global state which can be accessed via any component in your App, So you can assign the interval to a global state and use that state anywhere in your App.

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is that [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) will always return `undefined` (it has no return value). Meaning that:

> ```
> time === '00:05' && console.log('00:05 HIT') && clearInterval(callInterval);
> ```

Will [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#Short-circuit_evaluation) after the `console.log()` call.

Use an if-statement instead:

```
if (time === '00:05') {
  console.log('00:05 HIT');
  clearInterval(callInterval);
}
```

Alternatively you could use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), however I suggest sticking with the if-statement for better readability.

```
time === '00:05' && (console.log('00:05 HIT'), clearInterval(callInterval));
```

```js
true  && console.log("a") && console.log("b");
false && console.log("c") && console.log("d");

if (true) {
  console.log("e");
  console.log("f");
}

if (false) {
  console.log("g");
  console.log("h");
}

true  && (console.log("i"), console.log("j"));
false && (console.log("k"), console.log("l"));
```